# ActiveRecord Eager Load model that isn't belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm running into an issue with n+1 queries and I want to eager load a relationship, except I'm having trouble defining the relationship. It's complicated, haha, hear me out.

I have two models.

```
class Pokemon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pokemon_detail, primary_key: "level", foreign_key: "level"
end

class PokemonDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :pokemons, primary_ley: "level", foreign_key: "level"
end
```

Let's say, I have a the following record:

```
<Pokemon id: 1, name: "squirtle", level: 1>
```

Which would obviously correspond with the following `PokemonDetail`

```
<PokemonDetail id: 1, name: "squirtle", level: 1, health: 150>
```

And that can be easily eager loaded like `Pokemon.all.includes(:pokemon_detail)`, however, I want to eager load the information about one level higher.

```
<PokemonDetail id: 2, name: "squirtle", level: 2, health: 300>
```

I currently find the information about one level higher with the following method within the `Pokemon` model.

```
def next_level_info
  PokemonDetail.where(level: self.level + 1)
end
```

But this isn't eager loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: A `Pokemon` belongs to its detail? It doesn't make sense in meaning? `foreign_key: "level"` is super weak because maybe there are so many PokemonDetail has kind of that level

Comment: You're right, that is weak. I'm using the `CompositePrimaryKeys` gem, so I've got it two primary keys, name and level, but I figured that additional detail was irrelevant to the potential answer.

Comment: How about we refactor the schema to make it clear: Eg:


`Pokemon { has_many :pokemon_levels, attr_accessible :name, :current_level_value}` --- `PokemonLevel{ belongs_to :pokemon, attr_accessible :value, :health, :pokemon_id}`. Now you can use eager load easily for all pokemon levels

Comment: Do you have any additional documentation on your comment? Could you please post it as an answer? I'm not sure o completely understand because I thought attr_accessor was not a thing in rails 4?

Comment: Please check my answer, it is an example to make it work in your case

Answer (score 0):

1. Refactor schema first, to make it more sense:

   ```
   pokemons { current_level_value, name }
   pokemon_levels {value, pokemon_id (foreign key), health }
   ```
2. Redefine models like this:

   ```
   class PokemonLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :pokemon
   end


   class Pokemon < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :pokemon_levels
     has_one :current_pokemon_level, -> { joins(:pokemon).where('pokemons.current_level_value = pokemon_levels.value') },
          foreign_key: :pokemon_id, class_name: 'PokemonLevel'
     has_one :next_pokemon_level, -> { joins(:pokemon).where('pokemons.current_level_value + 1 = pokemon_levels.value') },
          foreign_key: :pokemon_id, class_name: 'PokemonLevel'
   end
   ```
3. Simply use it eg:

   ```
   Pokemon.includes(:current_pokemon_level, :next_pokemon_level).find(123)
   ```

I use `PokemonLevel` instead of `PokemonDetail`, because it is clearer to me